# My Qr scanner is slow and unable to decode

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I'm coding QR Reader using library com.google.zxing. It rarely be able to decode right and take 1-2 min to decode ,please help. here is my code

```
    String ReadSomeQRcode( )
{
    final Bitmap bitmap = //GetBitmapFromSimulatorCamera;
    final Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 390,230,500, 500);

    int[] intArray = new int[500 * 500];
    resizedbitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, resizedbitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, resizedbitmap.getWidth(), resizedbitmap.getHeight());

    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(resizedbitmap.getWidth(), resizedbitmap.getHeight(), intArray);

    Hashtable<DecodeHintType, String> hints = new Hashtable<>();
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET,"utf-8");

    QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
    try {
        com.google.zxing.Result result = reader.decode(new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source)),hints);
        return result.getText();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

p.s. I also can't debug because the simulator is on the server and I didn't have the permission to see the terminal.

Comment: Does the function "ReadSomeQRcode" need 1-2 minutes to finish execution or does the line "reader.decode..." need 1-2 minutes to decode?

Comment: I think the copying bitmap to binarybitmap make the process slower. reader.decode isn't slow but it's not accurate enough. I have try to decrease the size of the image and it's faster now but not very accurate.

Comment: In the first line you use a Bitmap. Can you get the image as a "BufferedImage"?
That would allow to use LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image); and you get rid of the intArray  and the getPixels call. That might speed things up.

Comment: The simulator's camera output is only give Bitmap. Can I convert from Bitmap to BufferedImage? is it more accurate?

Comment: Well, you can, but that won't be fast. I wanted to lower the amount of conversions using the BufferedImage. If you convert Bitmap to BufferedImage you introduce a new conversion just to get rid of another one. This wouldn't help I guess. I'm out of ideas and can't test it here either.

Comment: Actually,now I just want it to be more accurate can you help me with crop image?

Comment: What's your problem with the cropping?

Comment: I think if I have to call intArray i can crop image only the part of QR to make array smaller and faster to decode but I didn't know much about the right way to crop so after I cropped. It can't decode anyfurther but in my previous code which doesn't crop also can't decode now. I have no idea what happen too but I think if I do code wrong way to crop then my QR won't fill cropped image so when I fill it into decoder it doesn't work that's what i think now.

Comment: Okay that's not it the reader.decode make the process slow and not accurate please help

Comment: well, difficult to give any advice. I'd have to see some images. Without images I can hardly tell, why it's not accurate. But if the call to reader.decode() is slow, then I dont know what you can do about it. Only thing that might help, is to resize the image and make it less big than 500x500 px.

Comment: this is what it looks like [link]https://imgur.com/aRvnMAq  the resolution is 1280*960px. I zoom the image a little bit to take screenshot more clear but I think what camera seen must be more clear that this image, I swear.

Comment: It always slow and even slower while first scan